# Using the indefinite double integral

Tags: indefinite-integrals, surface-integrals

I have a plane $z=f$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. I would like to calculate the volume under the plane. I think I should express it as a double integral. With a "regular" integral I would find the indefinite integral first and then plug in limits: $F(a)-F(b)$. However I am unsure as to how this works with double integrals. Given the limits below, how do you express the volume with the antiderivative?

$$\int^b_a\int^d_c f(x,y)dxdy $$

Thankful for any help!

Comment: You take the antiderivative in $x$, then use the inner limits $c$ and $d$, then take the antiderivative in $y$, then use the outer limits $a$ and $b$. Just work from the inside out.

Comment: So you would never take the antiderivative twice and then plug in your limits?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by that. Do you mean take the antiderivative in $x$ and then in $y$ to get a function $F(x, y)$, then compute $F(d, b) - F(c, a)$? You can check in examples that this doesn't give the right answer but the procedure I gave does even for the constant function $f(x, y) = 1$.

Comment: How about something like $F(d,b)+F(d,a)+F(c,b)-F(c,a)$ ? Because that looks a lot like the expression you get with the "regular" method

Comment: Yes, that works, but I don't think it's really any easier than what I suggested, and it doesn't generalize to the case where $c$ and $d$ are not constant but are allowed to depend on $y$.

Comment: Okay, ah yeah that makes sense! Thanks a lot!